# Put comparator to bundle

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a lib for lists. Objects in list need to be sorted in client-defined way. So client writes a number of Comparators (by name, by price, etc) and passes them to library helper. We need to place those comparators to `HashMap<Integer, Comparator>` in order to put this map to `Bundle`, which is passed to `Fragment`. And the trouble I'm facing here is that Comparator is not Serializeable so I see runtime exception((

Comment: why do you need to serialize the comparator interface??

Comment: Define an interface that extends `Comparable` and `Parcelable`. Have the client app implement that interface. Then, you can place the objects in the `Bundle`. That being said, you might consider using some other approach (e.g., retained fragment, client subclasses your fragment class).

Comment: @CommonsWare > Have the client app implement that interface.  if we'll ask a client to implement some interface wouldn't it be easier to implement something like this?  public Comparator provideComparator(int indexOfSortMethod) {  return comparators.get(indexOfSortMethod);}

Comment: @Tau: I have no idea if that will be easier or not. I was trying to more closely model how you described your existing approach. You wrote "client writes a number of Comparators (by name, by price, etc) and passes them to library helper". Then you were having problems storing `Comparators` in a `Bundle`. If, instead, "client writes a number of ParcelableComparators (by name, by price, etc) and passes them to library helper" (where `ParcelableComparator` extends `Parcelable` and `Comparator`), your existing structure should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem (sort by price, by proximity, by name, by address) some time ago and solved it by saving in the bundle the list of items (the items must be instances of some class that implements IParcelable) and the sorting parameter (if any). Then, when restoring the Bundle I got the parcelableArray of items as well as the sorting method, setting the value properly in the activity / fragment.

Notice that this way you recover the list of items in the same order as they were saved, so everything works as expected.

IMHO that's much easier that what you're trying to accomplish by bundling a Comparator.

UPDATE: Example:

1.- The model implements IParcelable:

```
public class Parking implements Parcelable {
...
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeInt(mId);
        parcel.writeString(mCode);
        ...
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Parking> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Parking>() {
        public Parking createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Parking(in);
        }

        public Parking[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Parking[size];
        }
    };
}
```

2.- In the fragment / activity, I use an ArrayList of my model that implements IParcelable and the filter applied:

```
private ArrayList<Parking> mParkings;
private ParkingsFilter mFilter;
```

3.- When saving / restoring, I take this items into account:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(PARKING_LIST, mFragment.getParkings());
        savedInstanceState.putInt(CURRENT_FIRST_PARKING, mFragment.getCurrentFirstVisibleParking());
        savedInstanceState.putString(CURRENT_SEARCH_QUERY, mFilter.getCurrentQuery());
...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<Parking> parkings = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(PARKING_LIST);
        mFragment.setParkings(parkings);
        int currentFirstVisibleItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_FIRST_PARKING);
        mFragment.setCurrentFirstVisibleParking(currentFirstVisibleItem);
        mFilter.setCurrentQuery(savedInstanceState.getString(CURRENT_SEARCH_QUERY));
   ...
    }
```

Thus I save the whole list and I recover it in the same order as saved; on the other hand I recover the sorting option applied to set the values properly when restoring the bundle.

The key here is the **.getParcelableArrayList(), .putParcelableArrayList()** calls. Filters can be saved as an enum or simple integers / strings... as you will.

Additionally, I included in the example the "currentFirstVisibleItem" which is not directly related to this particular issue but may be useful; it's related to properly setting the scroll to the value it has before destroying the Activity / Fragment.

Comment: Are you talking about creating some synthetic class which only purpose would be parcelling data? Could you please provide example code in order to clarify things out.

Comment: Sure, let me find an example of the point I want to explain, I hope it helps ;)